# How to change size of Adaptive Card within message

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, adaptive-cards

When I add an Adaptive Card as an attachment to a message, the size is always limited to some amount, despite the message itself being much larger. Is there a way to specify the size of an Adaptive Card, or to force it to fill the width of the message?

[image: Example of card constrained to a certain width]

Comment: Are you using the Bot Framework WebChat control?

Comment: @MattHidinger This was on the emulator.

Comment: @ApurvaKoti Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: @Vijay I wasn't able to solve it, I just carried on with the fixed width attachment. I haven't worked with the Bot Framework since this message was posted, so it is possible that things are different now.

Answer (score 1):

The "Full Width" Adaptive Card functionality was released at some point and is now available.  I haven't tested it, but it might help with this situation.

Microsoft has documented how it works:

> ### [Constructing full width cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card)
>
> To make a full width Adaptive card the
> width object in `msteams` property in the card content must be set to
> Full. In addition, your app must include the following elements:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [{
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Digest card",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        }]
    }],

    "msteams": {
        "width": "Full"
    },
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```